# saltstack proxy minion execution fails to list files and directory

Tags: salt-stack

Me running slatstack minion in Windows machine and want to keep Ubuntu Linux as a proxy machine (consider this as dummydevice) for my POC work. The Ubuntu.sls file contains

```
proxy:
    dumbdevice1:
       proxytype: networkswitch
       host: 172.168.56.101 
       username: viswesn
       passwd: viswesn123
       cmd.run:
          - name: ls -l
          - cwd: /home/viswesn/
```

and I am expecting the Window minion to connect the Ubuntu machine (dummy device) using  the credential provided and run the command  "ls" in the directory "/home/viswesn/";

Unfortunately, it is not happening as I expected; 
I got the following message on running

```
cmd> salt-call state.highstate -l debug

...
...
[DEBUG   ] Results of YAML rendering:
OrderedDict([('base', OrderedDict([('*', ['ubuntu'])]))])
[DEBUG   ] Jinja search path: ['c:\\salt\\srv\\pillar']
[DEBUG   ] Rendered data from file: c:\salt\srv\pillar\ubuntu.sls:
 proxy:
    dumbdevice1:
       proxytype: networkswitch
       host: 172.168.56.101
       username: viswesn
       passwd: viswesn123
       cmd.run:
         - name: ls -l
         - cwd: /home/viswesn/
       [DEBUG   ] Results of YAML rendering:
       OrderedDict([('proxy', OrderedDict([('dumbdevice1',     OrderedDict([('proxytype', 'networkswitch'), ('host', '172.168.56.101'), ('username', 'viswesn'), ('passwd', 'viswesn123'), ('cmd.run', [OrderedDict([('name', 'ls -l')]), OrderedDict([('cwd', '/home/viswesn/')])])]))]))])
       Function state.proxy is not available
       ...
```

Is I am missing something? How can I resolve this issue? Please guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Can you provide the url of the documentation you're following?  When you're calling ```salt-call state.highstate``` that wouldn't do anything on the proxy minion, just the windows minion you're on.

Comment: After following couple of documents, I understand that I need to create a proxytype named python file (networkswitch.py) to speak to the dummy device; but still I have no idea on what kind of communication that I can use to speak with Ubuntu machine (Consider as dummy device); to list the files under the specified directory given at run time by the user.